# Carrierwave only upload image when update action when using Rails 4 and nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, strong-parameters

My model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_images, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images, :reject_if => lambda { |p| p['image'].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end


class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  mount_uploader :image, ProductImageUploader
  validates_presence_of :image
end
```

My controller:

```
  def create
    @product = Product.new(permitted_params.product)
    if @product.save
        redirect_to edit_admin_product_path(@product), notice: "success"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update_attributes(permitted_params.product)
      redirect_to edit_admin_product_path(@product), notice: "success"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

permitted_params:

```
class PermittedParams < Struct.new(:params)
  def product
    params.require(:product).permit(*product_attrs)
  end

  def product_attrs
    [:name, :content, :stock, :list_price, :selling_price, :bonus, :is_added,
     product_images_attributes: [:id, :image, :_destroy] ]
  end
end
```

And parameters passed:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eqweq1231sda+3T0131643guXybT75X6NqN1ng=", "product"=>{"name"=>"weqwe", "content"=>"qweq", "product_images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image"=>"1069218_513152615405563_1187314087_n.jpg", "_destroy"=>""}}, "stock"=>"", "list_price"=>"", "selling_price"=>"123", "bonus"=>""}, "commit"=>"submit"}
```

Obviously the image is pass to the params. but when create product it will rollback to alarm the image is empty(validate presence image in my ProductImage model).

If I delete the validation then create the product. I can successfully upload the images in update action. I have totally no idea what's the problem! Please help. Q_Q

Comment: trying to check why is image is `1069218_513152615405563_1187314087_n.jpg` technically it should be a file object don`t you think

Comment: Big thanks Viren! I didn't notice that at all. It turns out I create a wrong form at my new template!!

Comment: Please add a comment on the question so that everyone knows that  it has been solved